# Синонимизировать [настройки]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки

- [settings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings) (78 вопросов)
- [настройки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8) (74 вопроса)

надо бы синонимизировать.

Comment: [tag:настройка] может быть в смысле "set up", а не "settings"

Comment: Метку [tag:настройка] убрал - с ней действительно не ясно. А что касается [tag:setup] (такая метка тоже есть) - то её используют на очень многие темы.